# How to know which items are in a QGraphicsItemGroup?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I do not seem to find anywhere in the documentation how to find which QGraphicsItem belongs to a QGraphicsItemGroup knowing the group. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qgraphicsitemgroup.html#details):

> A QGraphicsItemGroup is a special type of compound item that treats
>   itself and **all its children** as one item.

So all group's children belong to the group.

`QGraphicsItemGroup` is derived from `QGraphicsItem`, which has this function:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *> QGraphicsItem::childItems() const
```